# Tables not joining using options to find()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to join the following two tables in a controller:

```
artifacts_publications
----------------------
id
artifact_id
publication_id
```

and

```
authors_publications
--------------------
id 
author_id
publication_id
```

Other tables which have associations like belongsTo and HasMany set up easily join using `contain()`. For these tables, suppose no association is already defined. In the end, I want to join another table to the join of these tables but for now I cannot get these two joined.

The Controller uses

```php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
    use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
```

In the `index()` action of the controller, I have

```php
$options['joins'] = [
    [
        'table' => 'authors_publications',
        'alias' => 'j',
        'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
        'conditions' => [
            'authors_publications.publication_id = artifacts_publications.publication_id',
        ],
    ],
];

$query = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('artifacts_publications')->find('all', $options);
$query->limit(2);

debug($query);
debug($query->toArray());
```

The resulting SQL query is somewhat like this, but I have shortened long identifiers:

```sql
SELECT id, artifact_id, publication_id 
FROM artifacts_publications
LIMIT 2;
```

Executing that query also shows no join. I tried to follow [cakePHP table joining two tables issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809246/cakephp-table-joining-two-tables-issue) but I still cannot join. Hand-written SQL worked but it is not elegant. What am I missing here?

Comment: [**The option**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data) is named `join` (after [**the method with the same name**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)), not `joins`

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that for a few days. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Utsav

Try to use the `Containable` behaviour of CakePHP by switching the 'join' with 'contain'.

```
$options = [
            'fields' => [
                'ArtifactsPublication.fieldsYouWant'
            ],
            'conditions' => [
                'ArtifactsPublication.id' => $artifactId
            ],
            'contain' => [
                'AuthorsPublication'
            ]
        ];
```

You can also set the recursive to define if you want to get the contained model's linked models. Alternativly you can specify in the `fields` option what fields you want from the `artifacts_publications` Model and then just `contain` the `authors_publications` Model.

Hope this helps as I have had bad experiences with manual joins in CakePHP, also the CakePHP standard is to use `contain`. Just note a `contain` cannot retrieve distant joined data.

Cheers mate :)